# Issue with Firebase database REST API URL having character "." i.e. period

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase is not able to store data if any of the node in the json tree path contain character "." i.e period

Example

*https://.firebaseio.com/path/to/node/.json*
Will store the data in above specified json tree node.

However, consider below query where I have a "." character in my url

*https://.firebaseio.com/path/to/node.speical/.json*

It will return

```
{
"error": "Invalid path: Invalid token in path"
}
```

Is this something because firebase server have not handled this case appropriately??
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are a set of special characters that Firebase does not support in it's keys. From Firebase doc -

> A child node's key cannot be longer than 768 bytes, nor deeper than 32
>   levels. It can include any unicode characters except for . $ # [ ] /
>   and ASCII control characters 0-31 and 127.

You need to escape or encode those characters if they are present in your key. A simple character substitution encoding will work too.

Comment: thank you guys. I wished if this was handled at firebase end since now I have to replace the "." char from all my node data if its present.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the Firebase Database through its REST API, your URLs will end in `.json`. But aside from that, the `.` character is not allowed in Firebase Database paths. So `node.special` is not a valid node name.

Comment: Frank, youre a developer at firebase, you should find a work-around to this. I wanted links to be my key, but now i'll have to find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SrujanBarai. We've discussed allowing periods many times before, but so far have decided against it. If you'd like to weigh in, I recommend [filing a feature request for it](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: If you've already decided against it, i'd happily accept it :)